# Where can I ask about Ansible 2.3.0 becoming available as ppa?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On what Stack Exchange site can I ask when Ansible 2.3.0 becomes available?

One could ask this question on Server Fault or on the DevOps Stack Exchange site, but it is not a technical question.

I would like to consult a web page that indicates when what Ansible becomes available. I have googled, but I did not find such a page and I do not know on what Stack Exchange site such questions should be asked.

Comment: Since you don't actually ask the question here (it's off topic on MSE), "What have you tried" is not relevant, unless you tell where you asked this before and if it was closed, etc. (Not on Github, which isn't part of SE.)

Comment: I don't believe that a question about future events is on topic anywhere in the network. This is a question to ask the Ansible developers, no one else.

Comment: Here https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are some sites in the SE network of sites that focus on prediction, guessing and shaping the future, your specific question wouldn't be a good fit for any of the SE sites.

When a product becomes available is at best known by the people who make that product. And then you still risk that the answer will be: *ships in May but it might take until the 48th of May*.

Shipping dates can only be guessed by people and once it shipped the question and it's answers become [trivia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEmcA.jpg). That is not useful for future visitors.

You better direct such questions directly to the source, being a company or the maintainers, who build the product.